# React hooks state not using latest

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I have the below code where I want to create a list of tags. In this example I'm fetching a list of tags in `setAllTags()` and then a number of available tags in `setAvailableTags()`.

Then problem that I have is that when `setAvailableTags()` is run it will remove the tags that was fetched in `setAllTags()`. It seems like the state that I set in `setAllTags()` is not used when `setAvailableTags()` is settings it's state.

Any idea what I can do to fix this?

https://codesandbox.io/s/rj40lz6554

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

const Search = () => {
  const [tags, setTags] = useState({
    all: [],
    available: []
  });

  const setAllTags = () => {
    const all = ["tag 1", "tag 2", "tag 3"];
    const newValue = {
      ...tags,
      all
    };
    console.log("setting all tags to ", newValue);
    setTags(newValue);
  };

  const setAvailableTags = () => {
    const available = ["tag 1", "tag 2"];
    const newValue = {
      ...tags,
      available
    };
    console.log("setting available tags to", newValue);
    setTags(newValue);
  };

  useEffect(setAllTags, []);
  useEffect(setAvailableTags, []);

  return (
    <div>
      <div>
        <select placeholder="Tags">
          {tags.all.map((tag, i) => (
            <option key={tag + i} value={tag}>
              {tag}
            </option>
          ))}
        </select>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

const App = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Hello React!</h1>
      <Search />
    </div>
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("app"));
```

The console is logged with

```
setting all tags to Object {all: Array[3], available: Array[0]}
setting available tags to Object {all: Array[0], available: Array[2]}
```

Comment: You should not set state inside useEffect.

Comment: It is totally fine to set state inside `useEffect`.

Comment: Not in the case when there is no guard condition. It will run forever.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the react docs, you can see how `useEffect` works (https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html)

> Experienced JavaScript developers might notice that the function passed to useEffect is going to be different on every render. This is intentional. In fact, this is what lets us read the count value from inside the effect without worrying about it getting stale. Every time we re-render, we schedule a different effect, replacing the previous one. In a way, this makes the effects behave more like a part of the render result — each effect “belongs” to a particular render. We will see more clearly why this is useful later on this page.

What this means, is that each side effect within your render function will only have access to the initial result of `useState`. Remember that react states are immutable, so it doesn't make sense for you to update the state, and then try and use the updated version within the same render cycle.

You can see this by simply calling:

```
setTags({ all: ['test'] })
console.log(tags)
```

You should notice that `tags` does not change at all.

Personally I would use hook conventions here, and separate your useState out into two separate variables:

```
const [allTags, setAllTags] = useState([])
const [availableTags, setAvailableTags] = useState([])
```

This makes your effects more explicit (as they only need to update the one variable), and improves readability.

Comment: Thx Matt, I see by the number of answers that there are multiple ways of solving this but this is the approach I settled it.

Comment: The way hooks are described they are a leaky abstraction. Because it leaks the inner workings. If the manual was more explicit and less "afraid" of showing complexity; react hooks could possibly be a more natural abstraction.

Answer (score 5):

`setTags` changes the internal react state and doesn't change the value of `tags` directly. So it doesn't get updated till the next render.

Use this call instead:

```
setTags(currentTags => ({...currentTags, all}));
```

And do the same with `available`.

Answer (score 1):

from: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usestate

> Unlike the setState method found in class components, useState does not automatically merge update objects. You can replicate this behavior by combining the function updater form with object spread syntax:

```
setState(prevState => {
  // Object.assign would also work
  return {...prevState, ...updatedValues};
});
```

> Another option is useReducer, which is more suited for managing state objects that contain multiple sub-values.

And if you want to `setAvailableTags()` to be based on `setAllTags()` you should do
`useEffect(setAvailableTags, [tags.all])`

working example: https://codesandbox.io/s/5vzr20x99p?from-embed

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that when you useEffect with second parameter [], the function will be called only the first time the component is rendered. But because you use setState in it the component is rerendered, but the useEffect doesn't get called and so it won't update properly. One way you can fix your problem is by not using setState in each of the function but instead return the data to a another function which then sets the state like so.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

const Search = () => {
  const [tags, setTags] = useState({
    all: [],
    available: []
  });

  const setAllTags = () => {
    const all = ["tag 1", "tag 2", "tag 3"];
    return all;
  };

  const setAvailableTags = () => {
    const available = ["tag 1", "tag 2"];
    return available;
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    const all = setAllTags();
    const available = setAvailableTags();
    setTags({
      all: all,
      available: available
    });
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      <div>
        <select placeholder="Tags">
          {tags.all.map((tag, i) => (
            <option key={tag + i} value={tag}>
              {tag}
            </option>
          ))}
        </select>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

const App = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Hello React!</h1>
      <Search />
    </div>
  );
};

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

And you can use Promise.all() if you need to fetch the data from an API.

Comment: ``const available = setAvailableTags(all);`` would be better option, because we want to setAvailableTags based on all tags

Comment: For the expanded scenario for sure, but not in this case scenario.

Answer (score 0):

For the initial render, your `tags` is

```
{
  all: [],
  availableTags:[]
}
```

So for both the `useEffect` functions update this initial object.
And your `useEffect` functions are not called on state update.

You can use them like following:

```
const setAvailableTags = () => {
  const available = ["tag 1", "tag 2"];
  setTags(prevTags => ({...prevTags, available}));
};

useEffect(setAllTags, []);
useEffect(setAvailableTags, [tags.all]);
```