# Why would a value get stale using closure in React?

Tags: reactjs, use-effect

In [the documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html) for `useEffect()` it shows the following example:

```js
function Example() {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);

  useEffect(() => {
    document.title = `You clicked ${count} times`;
  });
}
```

It then says:

> Experienced JavaScript developers might notice that the function
> passed to `useEffect` is going to be different on every render. This is
> intentional. In fact, this is what lets us read the `count` value from
> inside the effect without worrying about it getting stale. Every time
> we re-render, we schedule a different effect, replacing the previous
> one.

I don't understand why `count` would get stale inside `useEffect()` since `useEffect` has `count` within its closure. Since `useEffect()` is a hook, shouldn't it always have access to the latest state variable? Also, in general, how can I be sure that I always have the latest value for a state variable?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [React hooks state not using latest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55221449/react-hooks-state-not-using-latest)

Comment: I recommend to use this approach: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46160461/how-do-you-set-the-document-title-in-react

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I don't understand why count would get stale inside useEffect() since useEffect has count within its closure.

Keep in mind that `Example` is going to be called multiple times, once for every render. So there are N renders, N `count` variables, and N useEffect functions. So it's true that each effect function has `count` within its closure, but each of them has a **specific** `count` within its closure. Whatever value it had when the closure was created, that's the value it will have when the effect runs. If you only created the function once, closing over the first value of `count`, then that code would only ever see the first value of `count` (ie, 0).

> Also, in general, how can I be sure that I always have the latest value for a state variable?

If you're setting state, then you can always access the latest value by using the function version of setState. For example:

```
setCount(prev => /* calculate new state from prev */)`
```

For other cases, either include the state in the dependency array of your useEffect, so that the effect re-runs when the count changes:

```
useEffect(() => {
  // some code that uses `count`
}, [count]);
```

Or leave the dependency array off entirely if you want the effect to run on every render.

```
useEffect(() => {
  // some code that uses `count`
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, this is a really good explanation. Since every React state is immutable anything that isn't explicitly saved will be re-created.