# why this function is behaving weirdly?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, object, react-state

I've a state named `modal` in my React App. The initial value is an object that says `{show: false, photo: null}`.

I've two buttons in the page. One is calling the `close` function and another is calling the `open` function. `open` is setting the state to `{show: true, photo: true}` and `close` is just logging `modal`

I also wrote some code to call the `close` function when the `Esc` button is clicked.

Here's my code:

```js
function App() {
  const [modal, setModal] = useState({ show: false, photo: null });

  // open func
  function open() {
    setModal({ show: true, photo: true });
  }

  // close func
  function close() {
    console.log(modal);
  }

  // function for esc key press
  function escFunc(event) {
    if (event.key === `Escape`) {
      close();
    }
  }
  useEffect(() => {
    document.addEventListener(`keydown`, escFunc, true);

    return () => {
      document.removeEventListener(`keydown`, escFunc, true);
    };
  }, []);

  return (
    <>
      <button onClick={open}>open</button>
      <br />
      <button onClick={close}>close</button>
    </>
  );
}
```

so now when I click the `open` button and then click the close button, it's logging `{show: true, photo: true}` (as expected). but the problem comes in if I press `Esc` now. It should log `{show: true, photo: true}` (as the state is already updated by the `open` function), but it's logging `{show: false, photo: null}` as if the state hasn't changed yet

Why is it happening?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why would a value get stale using closure in React?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72075881/why-would-a-value-get-stale-using-closure-in-react)

Comment: @Konrad can you please tell me why you suggested wrapping `escFunc` with `useCallback()` in Giorgi's answer? will it make any important changes?
as far I know, `useCallback()` should be used when a function is causing unnecessary re-renders in your component and you wanna cache that function. And `useCallback()` should only be considered as a performance optimization

Comment: [docs](https://beta.reactjs.org/reference/react/useCallback): *useCallback is a React Hook that lets you cache a function definition between re-renders.* -`useCallback` is usually used if you want one function reference in each render. Your `useEffect` is calling `escFunc` so you should add this function to the dependency array, but it would cause calling `useEffect` in each render, so `useCallback` would prevent that

Comment: i can just add `escFunc` in the dep array of `useEffect()` and it'll do the job I guess. why would I need to cache it?

Comment: @PratikDev my previous suggestion doesn't make sense. What about moving `escFunc` into the useEffect, and add `modal` to the dependency array?

Comment: @evolutionxbox yes that's exactly what i did

Answer (score 0):

Whenever a component rerenders, the entire function is reran.

In your `useEffect`, which is only called on the first render, you call `document.addEventListener` with the callback function `escFunc`. This `escFunc` has a closure that stores the value of `modal`, which is a reference to the original object state `{ show: false, photo: null }`.

In your `open` function, you set the state to `{ show: true, photo: true }` using the object literal syntax, which creates a whole new object with a new reference location.

The event listener is still tracking the original object.

To be able to get the new state reference, you need to remove the old event listener and then add a new event listener.

There are multiple ways to do this.

```js
useEffect(() => {
  document.addEventListener(`keydown`, escFunc, true);
  return () => {
    document.removeEventListener(`keydown`, escFunc, true);
  };
}, [modal]); // add modal to dep array
```

```js
useEffect(() => {
  document.addEventListener(`keydown`, escFunc, true);
  return () => {
    document.removeEventListener(`keydown`, escFunc, true);
  };
}, [escFunc]); // add escFunc to dep array, but this would run every render
```

Stylistically, this is the best option because it properly shows dependencies and doesn't have extra rerenders, but the calls to `useCallback` might make it slower

```js
const close = useCallback(function() {
  console.log(modal);
}, [modal]); // depends on modal

const escFunc = useCallback(function(event) {
  if (event.key === `Escape`) {
     close();
  }
}, [close]); // depends on close

useEffect(() => {
  document.addEventListener(`keydown`, escFunc, true);
  return () => {
    document.removeEventListener(`keydown`, escFunc, true);
  };
}, [escFunc]); // add escFunc to dep array
```

In fact, you don't even need to have `escFunc` outside of `useEffect` if you don't use it elsewhere

```js
const close = useCallback(function() {
  console.log(modal);
}, [modal]); // depends on modal

const escFunc = useCallback(function(event) {
  if (event.key === `Escape`) {
     close();
  }
}, [close]); // depends on close

useEffect(() => {
  function escFunc(event) {
    if (event.key === `Escape`) {
      close();
    }
  }

  document.addEventListener(`keydown`, escFunc, true);
  return () => {
    document.removeEventListener(`keydown`, escFunc, true);
  };
}, [close]); // add escFunc to dep array
```

Comment: I'm actually confused. are you suggesting to use `useCallback()` or not?

Comment: You can use `useCallback` to reduce the number of rerenders, but if your renders are cheap (like they are in the example) you don't need to worry about it